# How can I batch tag several hundred photos with separately recorded GPS data?

Tags: metadata, gps, exif

I have a large number of photos I would like to tag using data recorded with my GPS tracker. Ideally I would like to correlate the time-stamps of my photos with the positions reported by my tracker at those specific times.

What's the fastest and easiest way to achieve this?

**Note**: The pictures are standard jpeg files, the GPS data is formatted as a [KML file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CLI solution**

*Overview*

When dealing with metadata of any sort [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should always be the utility of choice. It comes with a plethora of different options and commands that allow you to tag images at your will.

For instance, if you want to tag all images in a specific folder with the geodata provided by a `KML` file you can use the following commands:

```
cd image_folder
exiftool -geotag gps.kml *.jpg
```

Of course there are far more options and settings available. For all the intricate details surrounding GPS-tagging with exiftool I'd advise you to consult [this section](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html) of the exiftool documentation.

*Installation*

exiftool is part of the official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

---

**GUI solution**

*Overview*

There are multiple front-ends to exiftool available. [GPicSync](https://github.com/notfrancois/GPicSync) is one that specializes in Geotagging images. The interface is simple and easy to use:

[image]

Having specified the image folder and the GPS file you want to use, you simply click on *Synchronize* to update the image metadata with GPS tags.

Additional options allow you to set a time offset and to even view your images in Google Earth.

*Installation*

Installing GPicSync requires manually setting up its dependecies and downloading the python source code. There have been [calls to package GPicSync](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/280844) in Ubuntu/Debian, but all available packages are outdated.

Here are the steps you will have to follow to install and set up GPicSync:

1. Install all dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl python-unidecode python-imaging python-wxgtk2.8
   ```
2. Check out the latest python source

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/notfrancois/GPicSync.git
   ```
3. Navigate to the cloned folder, make GPicSync executable, and run it:

   ```
   cd GPicSync
   chmod +x gpicsync-GUI.py
   ./gpicsync-GUI.py
   ```

That's it. GPicSync should be up and running. To better integrate the app into your system you could look into [creating a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/81372) for it.

I have tested these installation instructions on Ubuntu 12.04. Package names and dependencies might differ on newer releases.

---

**Converting between different GPS data formats**

*Overview*

One downside to GPicSync is that it only supports two input formats, GPX and NMEA. Compared to exiftool that's very little. However, if need-be you can always convert between different GPS data formats by using [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/). E.g., to convert from KML to GPX you could use the following command:

```
gpsbabel -i kml -f gps.kml -o gpx -F gps.gpx
```

Another option would be to use one of the many online converters such as [this one](http://gpx2kml.com/).

*Installation*

gpsbabel is part of the official Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install gpsbabel
```

Further reading on [gpsbabel](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPSBabel/Usage_from_the_command_line) usage.